# Can I make a TIdMappedPortTCP proxy specific clients to different destinations?

Tags: delphi, proxy, indy, lazarus

Using Indy Internet Direct for Delphi, with Lazarus on Linux, I developed an application which acts as a proxy with the purpose of redirecting clients to different content based on their IP address.

To do this, I used the `TIdMappedPortTCP` object.

### Some of the things I tried were:

1. To set the `OnConnect` notify event, and change the `AContext.Binding.Port`.
2. The one above, but the `OnBeforeConnect` notify event instead.
3. Again to change the `Binding.Port` but on `OnContextCreate`.
4. Changing the `TIdMappedPortTCP.MappedPort`

### Attempt

As an example, I have attempt number 2, which overrides `OnBeforeConnect`. I assume this attempt failed as `AContext.Connection.Connected` is already `true` at this stage, but I cannot find a way to modify It earlier than this.

```
procedure TMapperApplication.OnBeforeConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  IP, Host: string;
var
  I: integer;
begin
  // List
  Inc(ConnectionCount);
  AddConnection(AContext);

  // Write
  WriteDate;

  IP := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
  Host := GStack.HostByAddress(IP);

  TConsole.TextColor := TConsoleColor.LightMagenta;
  TConsole.Write := 'Incoming connection from ';
  TConsole.TextColor := TConsoleColor.LightBlue;
  TConsole.Write := Format('"%S" (%S) on port %D', [Host, IP, AContext.Binding.Port]);

  WriteNewLn;

  // Common date
  WriteDate;

  // Redirect port
  for I := 0 to High(Servers) do
    if IP = Servers[I].Source then
      begin
        AContext.Binding.IP:=Servers[I].Host;
        AContext.Binding.Port:=Servers[I].Port;

        TConsole.TextColor := TConsoleColor.Yellow;
        TConsole.Write := 'Mapped connection to ';
        TConsole.ResetStyle;
        TConsole.WriteLn:=Format('%S:%D', [Servers[I].Host, Servers[I].Port]);
        ResetNewLn;
        Exit;
      end;

  // Default mapping
  if EnableDefault then
    begin
      AContext.Binding.IP:=Servers[I].Host;
      AContext.Binding.Port:=Servers[I].Port;
      Mapper.Active:=true;

      TConsole.WriteLn:='Mapped connection to default host.';
      Exit;
    end;

  // Mapping failed
  TConsole.TextColor:=TConsoleColor.Red;
  TConsole.WriteLn:='Connection was dropped. No mapping found.';
  AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
  TConsole.ResetStyle;
end;
```

### Why use IP to differentiate the client?

After I tackle this issue, I plan to replace the IP address detection, and use a way to detect `server1.site.com` and `server2.site.com`, but I'm unsure If that's even possible in Delphi with the available libraries. I tried `GStack.HostByAddress(AContext.Binding.PeerIP)`, but that returns an empty string. A problem for another time.

### Research

I would have also searched `www.indyproject.org`, but It seems the web server is down at the moment. The downloads do not work. There is also [this](http://www.e-iter.net/knowledge/indy9/007533.html), but It does not provide any information useful for this problem.

I also found [this](https://borland.public.delphi.internet.winsock.narkive.com/iNolp4M4/idmappedporttcp-multiple-hosts-and-ports) old forum, but unfortunately the solution seems to be outdated as `TIdMappedPortThread` is an undefined declaration and is not used in the `TIdMappedPortTCP`. Also [this](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/12/211739.html), but It's also outdated.

So currently, I have exhausted all the ideas I have. Maybe creating a custom `TIdMappedPortTCP` could help? But I'm unsure at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The older solution you found is for Indy 9, but the same approach still applies in Indy 10. Simply replace `TIdMappedPortThread` with `TIdMappedPortContext` in Indy 10.

You cannot change the `AContext.Binding.IP`/`Port`, that is the listening IP/port where the client connected to your proxy.

To change where the proxy forwards to next on a per-connection basis (ie, not using the `MappedHost`/`MappedPort` properties), then you have to use the `OnConnect` event not the `OnBeforeConnect` event, and cast `AContext` to `TIdMappedPortContext`, then cast its `OutboundClient` to `TIdTCPClient`, and then set its `Host` and `Port` as needed.

```
procedure TMapperApplication.OnConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  ...
  with TIdTCPClient(TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).OutboundClient) do
  begin
    Host := ...;
    Port := ...;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: That solution works like a charm. I didn't expect a double typecast for the Context. I must also thank you for your long service in in Delphi community, your name is on every Delphi forum I go to :)